# ¿Qué hacer cuando un objeto desaparece de la pantalla?

Tags: java, android

Tengo creado un círculo que se mueve hasta desaparecer de la pantalla. Mi duda es qué sucede una vez que ya no aparece en la pantalla, sigue funcionando, ¿debería crear un método que lo elimine una vez que sale de la pantalla?

Éste sería el código:

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView {

    Paint paint;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawCircle(x ,y, 100, paint);

        x = x + 5;

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor sería destruirlo para liberar memoria. Aunque todo depende de ti. ¿Volverías a usar ese mismo objeto en una instancia más adelante?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. No, no lo volvería a usar

Comment: Como te ha dicho @CrismanCarmona lo mejor sería destruirlo, ya que así liberarás memoria y más is no lo vas a volver a utilizar. Sería lo mejor.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Voy a destruirlo entonces

Answer (score 1):

Sí, sería recomendable eliminar el objeto una vez que sale de la pantalla. Si no lo haces, el objeto seguirá existiendo en la memoria de tu aplicación y consumirá recursos innecesarios. A medida que se generen más objetos y se muevan fuera de la pantalla, la cantidad de recursos utilizados aumentará, lo que podría afectar negativamente el rendimiento de la aplicación.

Para eliminar el objeto una vez que sale de la pantalla, puedes verificar si la posición del objeto está fuera de los límites de la pantalla y, si es así, eliminarlo. Puedes hacer esto en el método `onDraw()` agregando una condición que verifique si la posición `x` del objeto es mayor que el ancho de la pantalla (`canvas.getWidth()`) y si es así, elimina el objeto llamando a un método que lo haga.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías modificar el método `onDraw()` para eliminar el objeto una vez que sale de la pantalla:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawCircle(x ,y, 100, paint);

    x = x + 5;

    if(x > canvas.getWidth()) {
        eliminarObjeto();
    }

    invalidate();
}

private void eliminarObjeto() {
    // Aquí debes agregar el código para eliminar el objeto
}
```

En el método `eliminarObjeto()` debes agregar el código para eliminar el objeto de la memoria de tu aplicación. La forma en que lo haces dependerá de cómo estés manejando los objetos en tu aplicación. Podrías, por ejemplo, eliminar la referencia al objeto para permitir que el recolector de basura de Java lo elimine de la memoria automáticamente, o podrías eliminar el objeto manualmente usando un método como `System.gc()`.

Un ejemplo seria:

```
 private void eliminarObjeto() {
    // Mueve el objeto fuera de la pantalla para que no se dibuje más
    x = -200;
    y = -200;
    
    // Elimina la referencia al objeto
    paint = null;
    
    // Espera a que el recolector de basura elimine el objeto
    System.gc();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Según veo, ¿usarás el método onDraw() en un bucle? El caso es que el círculo sólo se moverá dentro del Canvas hasta el límite de "X". Debes preguntarte si seguirás usando ese objeto... En caso de que sí, sólo deberías reiniciar su ubicación y reutilizarlo en algún lugar.
En caso contrario puedes destruir el objeto o simplemente dejar que el garbage collector se encargue de él.

Comment: Por favor mira [answer]. Podrias ser mas claro con tu respuesta? se reporto como de baja calidad.

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre el mío y los de más arriba?